# Given a table of items with weighted probability, calculate the distribution of how many rolls it would take to go through all items.

Tags: probability, statistics, coupon-collector

### Here's my full question

> Given a table of items with weighted probability, calculate the distribution of how many rolls it would take to go through all items if each item decreases in weight n times.

I'm currently trying to make a video game with a random chance mechanic and want to see how, on average, many rolls it takes to exhaust my item list if each item has less chance of appearing (or is taken out completely of the pool) after *n* times.

Below I have more detail concerning my item table.

### Here's some more detail:

[Image of Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3M0vC.png)

**Item**    weight probability

**doll_Common_05**  250 14.07%

**doll_Common_06**  250 14.07%

**doll_Common_07**  750 42.21%

**doll_Common_08**  200 11.25%

**doll_Rare_01**    100 5.63%

**doll_Rare_02**    100 5.63%

**doll_Rare_03**    100 5.63%

**doll_Rare_04**    20  1.13%

**doll_Epic_01**    5   0.28%

**doll_Epic_02**    2   0.11%

Comment: What do you mean by "exhaust" and how do weights change?

Comment: I apologize for the wording. I mean how many rolls does it take until I get at least 1 of all items?

As for weights, I first want to know what the distribution is if the weights don't change. And if the weights change to 0 after being picked up _n_ times

Comment: See https://www.mathpages.com/home/kmath047.htm for fixed weight case. It answers your question a little bit more generally.

Comment: Thank you, upon reading it fully it does seem to answer my question in a more general way however I get confused on the use of variables L and s(N,k). Could you help me understand it?

I can't seem to understand the difference between L and kth partition and I don't understand what s(N,k) means